# Unknown behavior of images in HTML

Tags: css, html, html-table

I've created some newsletters lately and I am surprised I can't get over this issue.

Whenever I use  to put in an image, there's always a bit of a space right below the image. This is very stressful when you want to want to put multiple images in a vertical row. There's always this space of about 5px that's added below. 
I tried with an HTML document with only one table including some pictures, bordercollapse and borderless, but the same issue is still present.

It's only when i put images right next to each other. I experimented in this document, which has this problem I weirdly can't get over it.

Can you see what I can't see? I never had this before, that's why I am so confused!

**CSS**

```
table{
    -webkit-font-family:  Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -msie-font-family:  Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -moz-font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px solid black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title> 

</head>
<body> 
                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:#202020">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td bgcolor="#ababab" style="width:600px;">


                            <table bgcolor="#134326" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style=" border-collapse:collapse; max-width:600px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"><!--Content-table-->                                   
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="WM.jpg"><br>
                                        <img src="WM.jpg">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="WM.jpg">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>                                   
                            </table>

                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color:#202020;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the vendor prefixes for `font-family`? That should just be cross browser without prefix. Don't think they even exist

Comment: ...and tables? Nooooooo!

Comment: thanks to Paulie_D,  vertical-align: middle;  worked.